# RMarkdown not rendering Stan code chunk as code

Tags: r-markdown, stan

When I knit the following RMarkdown document:

---

````
title: "Reprex"
author: "Jeremy Colman"
date: "17/07/2018"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


 ```{stan, output.var='priors', eval = FALSE, tidy = FALSE}

parameters {
  real<lower = 0>  qtilde1;

}

model {
  qtilde1 ~ gamma(38.9, 0.67);

}
````

```

The Stan code chunk is rendered as ordinary text, including the three reverse single quotes and word stan from the chunk header. I cannot show that in this post because stackoverflow tells me, correctly but unhelpfully, "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code". That sums up my problem!

Code chunks in R are rendered correctly.

Comment: Many thanks, Ben. I really don't think that I inserted that leading space, but something did!

Comment: I have found what inserted the leading space: others beware! I was using R Studio to type my markdown document and R Studio frequently inserts leading spaces when one move to a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

````
 ```{stan output.var='priors', eval = FALSE, tidy = FALSE}
````

needs to be flush-left, but you have a leading space before the ```